# Convert Date Instance in local timezone

Tags: android

I have a date instance, how to convert it into local time zone?

```
Date meetingStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(model.StartDateTimeUtc);
```

Comment: Is there some specific time zone you want? Or it's a global app & you want local time zone based on device's location?

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

date == null ? dateStr : df.format(meetingStartDate );
```

Comment: Thanks but your code is confusing, how would I know what is "outpurFormat" paramter does, what is it's data type. Please mention it in proper format, also I am looking for output in Date format only

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get time in local time zone

```
Date meetingStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(model.StartDateTimeUtc);
DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
  System.out.println(formatter.format(meetingStartDate));
```